# Can't get an image search command to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I apologize in advance if the fix is really obvious.

So I'm following a youtube tutorial to make a discord bot command where it sends a random image based on a search term. Here is my code so far:

```js
function image(message){
    var options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + `hi`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome"

        }
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
        if(error){
            message.channel.send("There was an error trying to search for that image :(")
            return;
        }

        $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

        var links = $('.image a.Link');
        var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));
        console.log(urls);
        if(!urls.length){
            return;
        }

        message.channel.send(urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)] + " " + message.guild.members.random)
    })
}
```

when I try to run the command, it sends a message just saying "undefined undefined" (only sends the message when the code doesn't say to return if `!urls.length` if thats helpful) I've followed the tutorial and haven't noticed any differences. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the value of `urls`? Can you post that too?

Comment: When it logs `urls` all that gets logged is "[]"

Comment: Well, yeah, `$('.image a.Link')` should be `$('.image a.link')` as there are no `Link` class names on that page.

Comment: I changed it to `$('.image a.link')` and it still has the exact same problem.

Comment: Is `urls` still an empty array? (`[]`)

Comment: Yup, still sends a message saying "undefined undefined" also.

Comment: If `urls` is an empty array, it can't send a message as that part of code won't run. Have you checked the value of `links` too?

Comment: Yes, checked that and it sends a lot of text.

Comment: The code example is rather limited and makes it hard to help out without knowing more about your code. Perhaps add an example of the HTML you are running this against?